# assigns() method vs Binding - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm new to Ruby on Rails world.

I noticed there is at least one way to access controller instance variables from a test case.

Indeed, suppose this test method:

```
test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:products)
end
```

`products` is an instance variable contained within concerned controller. And for sure, test case has reference to this controller. So `assigns()` method uses it to inspect a hash of controller's instance variables and thus allows to access any precised object from any other files that previously called an action to this controller.

So I wonder two questions:

**Why do not create a 'Binding' to controller instead of using `assigns()` method?**

I imagine a version where it is possible to do:

```
test "should get index" do
        get :index
        assert_response :success
        assert_not_nil @products
end
```

Wouldn't it be shorter and cleaner?

Binding is the mechanism that allows ERB file to access controller instance variables, as shows this links:

http://rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system

What isn't this mechanism applicable to Test case ? Is `assigns()` method essential ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you brought over the binding, though, this might pass and should not

```
test "should get index" do
    @fake_products = [1,2,3]
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil @fake_products
end
```

You wouldn't necessarily want all instance variables in your test to combine with instance variables in your controller. Assigns lets you 'scope' your assertions to just the controller instance variables.